# Reading words from file error

Tags: c, file, tree, binary-tree

I've got a problem with reading words from file and passing it to binary tree. When I debug it, it says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76E7773B(ntdll.dll) in Projekt.exe: 0.C00000005:
    Access violation reading location 0x0037902A.
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Tree {
    int val;
    char *word;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
} Tree;

void show(Tree *hd) {
    if (hd != NULL) {
        show(hd->left);
        show(hd->right);
        printf("%s -- %d\n", hd->word, hd->val);
    }
}

void zero(Tree *aTree) {
    if (aTree == NULL)
        return;

    zero(aTree->left);
    free(aTree);
    zero(aTree->right);    
}

int alpha(char *word1, char *word2) {
    if (word1[0] == 0 && word2[0] == 0)
        return 2;
    else
    if (word1[0] == word2[0])
        return alpha(&word1[1], &word2[1]);
    else
    if (word1[0] < word2[0])
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

Tree *create(char *word) {
    Tree *temp;
    temp = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    temp->left = temp->right =  NULL;
    temp->val = 1;
    temp->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp->word, word);
    return temp;
}

Tree *insert(Tree *aTree, char *word) {
    if (aTree == NULL) {
        aTree = create(word);
    } else
    if (alpha(aTree->word, word) == 0) {
        aTree->left = insert(aTree->left,word);
    } else
    if (alpha(aTree->word, word) == 1) {
        aTree->right = insert(aTree->right, word);
    } else
    if (alpha(aTree->word, word) == 2) {
        aTree->val++;
    }
    return aTree;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tree *myTree = NULL;
    char buffer[256] = { 0 };
    char temp = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp)  {
        while (temp != EOF) {
            temp = getc(fp);
            temp = toupper(temp);
            if (temp >= 65 && temp <= 90) {
                buffer[i] = temp;
                i++;
            } else {
                if (buffer[0] != 0) {
                    puts(buffer);
                    myTree = insert(myTree, buffer);
                    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    show(myTree);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a *crash*. You should use the debugger to locate where it happens in *your* code (i.e. if the debugger stops in library code then go up the call stack until you're at your code).

Comment: By the way you should read e.g. [this `getc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), take note of the *returned type*, it's important!

Comment: And lastly a note about style, don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in your code, it makes the code harder to read. Either use actual character literals (like e.g. `'a'`) but that will still not be portable so you should use [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has several problems:

- in function `zero`, you free the pointer too soon, you should move the `free(aTree);` as the last statement, otherwise you invoke undefined behavior, possibly a crash (but not the one you have, since you never call this function):

  ```
  void zero(Tree *aTree) {
      if (aTree != NULL) {
          zero(aTree->left);
          zero(aTree->right);    
          free(aTree);
  }
  ```
- In function `alpha`, you use recursion where a simple loop would suffice. The compiler may convert this to a loop, but it does have to. This is not a bug but why not use a more idiomatic approach such as:

  ```
  int alpha(const char *word1, const char *word2) {
      for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
          if (word1[i] == '\0' && word2[i] == '\0')
              return 2;

          if (word1[i] == word2[i])
              continue;

          if (word1[i] < word2[i])
              return 1;
          else
              return 0;
      }
  }
  ```
- In function `create`, you allocate a single byte for the string, this is definitely a cause for the crash.  You should allocate `strlen(word) + 1` or use `strdup(word)`.  You should not cast the return value of `malloc()` either:

  ```
  Tree *create(const char *word) {
      Tree *temp;
      temp = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
      temp->left = temp->right =  NULL;
      temp->val = 1;
      temp->word = strdup(word);
      return temp;
  }
  ```
- In function `insert` you call `alpha` multiple times, this is inefficient: you could use a `switch` statement:

  ```
  Tree *insert(Tree *aTree, const char *word) {
      if (aTree == NULL) {
          return create(word);

      switch (alpha(aTree->word, word)) {
          case 0:
              aTree->left = insert(aTree->left, word);
              break;
          case 1:
              aTree->right = insert(aTree->right, word);
              break;
          case 2:
              aTree->val++;
              break;
          }
      }
      return aTree;
  }
  ```
- function `main` has multiple issues:

  - You do not check if `argv[1]` is provided to the program.  It would be `NULL` if the program is run without a command line argument.
  - Your test for end of file is incorrect: `temp` should be defined as `int` and you should test its value after reading the byte from the file with `getc()`, it is idiomatic to name `c` a variable used for this.
  - You should use character literals instead of hard coded ASCII values.
  - the test `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` would work for ASCII, which is almost universal today, but it is more reliable to use `isupper(c)` instead.
  - You do not need to clear the `buffer`, setting a `'\0'` at the end before inserting the word is enough.
  - You should also check for buffer overflow and refuse to handle words longer than 255 characters.
  - You should not call `fclose(fp)` when `fp` is `NULL`, this is undefined behavior.

  Here is a corrected version:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      Tree *myTree = NULL;
      char buffer[256];
      int c;
      size_t i;
      FILE *fp;

      if (argc < 2) {
          printf("missing argument\n");
          return 2;
      }

      fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if (fp == NULL)  {
          printf("cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
          return 1;
      }
      i = 0;
      while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
          c = toupper(c);
          if (isupper(c)) {
              if (i < sizeof(buffer))
                  buffer[i] = c;
              i++;
          } else {
              if (i > 0 && i < sizeof(buffer)) {
                  buffer[i] = '\0';
                  puts(buffer);
                  myTree = insert(myTree, buffer);
                  i = 0;
              }
          }
      }
      fclose(fp);
      show(myTree);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'm new at programing, but thanks to advices like yours I'm doing better.

Comment: @J.Kennsy: glad to help! Please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to accept this answer.  You can only upvote once you reach a reputation of 15.

Comment: I've applied your changes and program shows words in : puts(buffer); but it replaces current word in tree with buffer word and output is: THE -- 1

Comment: Your program converts words to uppercase before inserting them into the tree, Is this not your intent?